# DataTables cannot add row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datatables, typeerror

I'm trying to add data to a table dynamically through JavaScript, and it returns this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.

EDIT: The code works perfectly without the `row.add` line.

Relevant code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
var dataSet = [
    ['1.1','2.1'],
    ['1.2','2.2'],
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
    t = $('#example').dataTable( 
    {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { "title": "Col 1" },
            { "title": "Col 2" },
        ],
    });

    t.row.add(['1.3', '2.3']) // <-- Fails
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="demo" style="width:500px"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant see `t.row` declared/initialized in your code

Comment: did you debug and see the value for t.row? It is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. Here is the change I have done to your code:

a. While initializing DataTable, used capital D.
b. Used .draw(); while adding row.

```js
var dataSet = [
    ['1.1','2.1'],
    ['1.2','2.2']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');
 
    var t = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { "title": "Col 1" },
            { "title": "Col 2" }
        ]
    });             

    t.row.add(['1.3', '2.3']).draw(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" style="width:500px"></div>
```